# Default glassfish 4.0 password in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish-4

Well, more than a question this is an answer, I was trying to see for Glassfish 4.0 default admin password to access its console but I didn't find any satisfactory answer, some suggested to change admin-keyfile on glasssfish folder which can also work...  anyhow... here it is how I did it...

well, it turns out that it HAS a default password in the most recent version of netbeans, I discover that it is self-generated and it's not generic, to see your password go to services tab and then right click on your glassfish 4.0 server, then choose properties and then you'll see your password stored there on the common tab, click on show and you'll have your password...

hope to help you guys!

Comment: Why don't you post this in question format and then answer your own question. That's ok to do.

Comment: it was just because I was banned and couldn't answer any question, but you're right.

Comment: The answer for the latest [glassfish is here](http://superuser.com/questions/7654/how-to-reset-delete-my-glassfish-password)

Answer (score 8):

```
[root@ip-172-31-20-218 bin]# ./asadmin change-admin-password
Enter admin user name [default: admin]>admin
Enter the admin password>**[Note: as default password for admin in Glassfish 4.0 is blank, you need to press enter key only. Do not type any thing.]**
Enter the new admin password>
Enter the new admin password again>
Command change-admin-password executed successfully.
```

Answer (score 6):

I have used eclipse. I got the same issue I resolved it by doing the following.
For a fresh download of glassfish4.zip

1. Go to Glassfish_home/bin
2. Run `asadmin` start-domain
3. Open up http://localhost:4848
4. Click on Domain
5. Click on Administration Password
6. Give the new password and confirm
7. In the command prompt Run asaadmin stop-domain
8. Open the server in eclipse and give the username and password and start the server.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. And I solved it using a small trick. I removed the server installed with NetBeans from the interface and the added another. When you do this you may create a personal domain. And in this personal domain the anonymouns login is already enabled, with no password at all.

I know this is not a good solution, but it is a solution nonetheless.

Hope it helps!

PS: At least in my NetBeans 7.4 for Linux, sometimes when I leave NetBeans the servers won't go down. Then you have to kill their processes, or else you won't manage to install another due to port conflicts. It's a tricky thing to find the process of the server. When you use "ps -A" the name of the process is only "java", with no clue it is the server.

Comment: you could simply install another version of GF without uninstalling the dafult one, then just setting netbeans to use GF x.x version you use installed as a default for all your projects, but yes, it can be done that way but it's more work than just watching on the server's properties.

Comment: Agreed, but I only found out this by your comment here. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

As I know default glassfish password is 'changeit' for master admin and is empty for domain admin (with login admin by default). If you mean this password try this.